# How to explain that both the integration of inverse functions are correct?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know that we can find the integration of $\cos^{-1}(x)$ using two formulas

1. $\int\cos^{-1}(x)dx=\int udv-\int vdu$, choosing $u=\cos^{-1}(x)$ and $dv=dx$.

or

2. $\int f^{-1}(x)dx=xf^{-1}(x)-\int x\big(\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}\big)dx$, where $f^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}(x)$.

The answers I get after integrations are respectively

$$\int\cos^{-1}(x)dx=x\cos^{-1}(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$ and
$$\int\cos^{-1}(x)dx=x\cos^{-1}(x)-\sin(\cos^{-1}(x))$$
I know that both the integrals are correct but how to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin \arccos x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\arccos x}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$